# Gradle master config for independent projects

Tags: java, gradle, build, dependency-management

Is there any possibility to have some kind of master gradle config for independent projects?

Exp. I have three projects A, B and C which are independent of each other - most of build.gradle file is the same - is there any way to group this similarities in one build.gradle and import it to build.gradle of all the A, B and C projects?

Comment: Create a plugin? Or, if the projects are independent yet still subprojects of a multi-project build, then use [cross project configuration](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/multi_project_builds.html#sec:cross_project_configuration).

Comment: Yeah, but as shown for multi-project build they're still using the parent build.gradle to trigger the build. I want to trigger only "child" build.gradle which will import parents config.

Comment: I'm not sure there's a problem (the parent `build.gradle` file will always be processed, I believe). But you can always [create a plugin](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/custom_plugins.html). The plugin can be placed in a separate script [and applied](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/plugins.html#sec:script_plugins) to the child projects.

Comment: If anybody will face the same issue - I've created build.gradle with common config and dropped it in the artifactory. Then in your projects build.gradle just put `apply from: 'PUT_URL_HERE'`